# Is there a store selling T-Mobile SIM cards in Houston's IAH International Airport?

Tags: cellphones, shopping, iah

If so, which terminal? (Hopefully Terminal D.)

Specifically I'd like to buy a prepaid SIM card ideally without leaving IAH on a BYOD 'Simply Prepaid' T-Mobile plan for just one month while I am travelling around Southern USA and the Caribbean.

Comment: Subject to confirmation, as it's been a while (hence the comment), you may be able to get it in [SoundBalance](http://soundbalance.com/). There's one in Terminal C after security, and one in Terminal E near gate E24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While yes there is indeed a Best Buy vending kiosk in terminal D (and several other terminals) at Houston IAH, it does not (at this time) stock T Mobile SIM cards or phones.

There was a variety of electronic items such as MP3 players and headphones, and a 'SIM International' SIM starter pack. No USA based carrier SIM only kits were offered in this machine.

After speaking with Best Buy staff I was told that they no longer stock T-Mobile SIM cards at all, only several other brands.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a Best Buy automated kiosk in Terminal D that offers no-contract cellphones you can purchase. If you [visit here](http://www.fly2houston.com/iah/shop/) and filter by location to Terminal D, you will find more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, just that link alone is enough to answer my question. I'll try to remember to come back here and report exactly what kind of stock that vending machine had for future users.

Comment: Yes but does it sell T-Mobile? Or another brand?